# Take data from different tables and display it in View Index

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables `Job_table` and `Employee_table`. I want to display `emp_id` from `Job_table` and corresponding `emp_name` from `Employee_table` in the index view of `Employee_table`.

For that matter,I create a ViewModel `EmployeeViewModel` and bind the index view of my action result with an `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>`. The definition for EmployeeViewModel looks like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName  { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    //..Other memberVariables..
}
```

My models:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

And WorkTable, renamed it as Job for my own convenience:

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public JobCategory JobCategory { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index Action, I create a result set by joining the two tables, bind it to `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>` and pass that as a model to the view. The View should receive a model of type `IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel>` as I mentioned earlier, so I need to query my entities which should be something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //..something like this..this is IQueryable..
    //...convert this to IEnumerable and send this as the model to ..
    //..the Index View as shown below..here you are querying your own tables, 
    //.. Employee and Job,and binding the result to the EmployeeViewModel which
    //.. is passed on to the Index view.
    IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> model=null;
    model = (from c in db.Employees
                join q in db.Jobs on c.EmployeeId equals q.EmployeeId
                 from q in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 group new { q, c } by c into grp
                select new EmployeeViewModel
                {
                    EmployeeId = grp.Key.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName = grp.Key.EmployeeName,

                });

    return View(model);
}
```

I want to display the result like:

```
|Employee 1|
|----------|
| Job 1    |
| Job 2    |

|Employee 2|
|----------|
| Job 3    |
| Job 4    |
| Job 5    |
```

but now my result is

```
|Employee 1|  |Employee 1|
|----------|  |----------|
| Job 1    |  | Job 2    |

|Employee 2|  |Employee 2|  |Employee 2|
|----------|  |----------|  |----------|
| Job 3    |  | Job 4    |  | Job      |
```

How can I remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is called [LEFT JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) in the database world. There are a number of possibilities how two tables can be joined in SQL. Each variant delivers a different result. The default *JOIN* is an *INNER* join, meaning that every entity from the result set exists in **both** tables. 
The *LEFT* join means, that the entity may exists in both tables, but must not. If it does not exist in the second table, an empty result set is returned. An example with two tables *Person* and *Job*:

```
|Table Person  |   |Table Job       |
| Id | Name    |   | Id | Job       |
|----|---------|   |----|-----------|
| 1  | John    |   | 1  | Astronaut |
| 2  | William |   | 3  | Cashier   |
```

The default LINQ join is the *INNER* join:

```
var r =  from p in Person
            join j in Jobs on p.Id equals j.Id
            select ...
```

will deliver this result set:

```
| INNER JOIN  RESULT    |
| Id | Name | Job       |
|----|------|-----------|
| 1  | John | Astronaut |
```

The *LEFT* join will look in LINQ like this:

```
var r =  from p in Person
            join j in Jobs on p.Id equals j.Id into jobs
            from subjob in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select ...
                Job = subjob != null ? subjob.Job : "no job"
                 ...
```

And the result set now looks like this:

```
| LEFT JOIN  RESULT        |
| Id | Name    | Job       |
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  | John    | Astronaut |
| 2  | William | no job    |
```

A good visual explanation can be found in this article [A visual explanation of SQL joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Normally the default **join** in LINQ is the INNER JOIN, so only matching entities (that are in both tables) will be selected. You can do a [LEFT JOIN with LINQ using a second from with DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx):

```
model = (from e in db.Employees
            join j in db.Jobs on e.EmployeeId equals j.EmployeeId into jobs
            from subjob in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,
                JobName = subjob != null ? subjob.JobName : "no job entry"
            }).Distinct();
```

A good LINQ introduction from Microsoft can be found on MSDN: [101 LINQ samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin).

---

Group by could look like this:

```
model = (from e in db.Employees
            join j in db.Jobs on e.EmployeeId equals j.EmployeeId into jobs
            from subjob in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group e by e.EmployeeName into ge
            select new
            {
                Key = ge.Key,
                Data = ge
            });

foreach (var groupItem in model)
{
    foreach (var employeeViewModel in groupItem.Data)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, it works. But When i insert 2 row with same EmployeeId, It appears below
employee1 
job1
employee1
job2

and I want only employee1 be load, how I can do that, I think it look like distinct? Please and thanks you so much

Comment: What do you mean by `employee1 be load`? You said in your question `And I want to display both employees`.

Comment: thanks guys, display both is work. But When i insert 2 row with same EmployeeId, It appears below employee1 job1 employee1 job2 and I want only employee1 be load, how I can do that, I think it look like distinct? Please and thanks you so much

Comment: Yes, use the [Distinct extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx): `model.Distinct()`. I have modified the code in my answer.

Comment: tnanks for your example.
I put distinct() but it doesn't work

model = (from e in db.Employees
            join j in db.Jobs on e.EmployeeId equals j.EmployeeId into jobs
            from subjob in jobs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new EmployeeViewModel
            {
                EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName,
                JobName = subjob != null ? subjob.JobName : "no job entry"
            }).distinct();

how I put distinct() in?

Comment: Did you tried with capital **D**, not **d** - **.Distinct();** and not **.distinct()**?

Comment: Yes, I use .Distinct(). And in View I use @foreach (  var p in Model) { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> p.EmployeeId) 
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> p.JobId)}. Is it right?

Comment: Hi guy, about A good LINQ introduction from Microsoft can be found on MSDN: 101 LINQ samples. 

My hopes is Group Join - LinQ 103. How can I do that? May you help me

Comment: What exactly is the problem - are there duplicate entries in the result? If you are not sure how to proceed, start by drawing your tables resp. data on a piece of paper. Look  how the tables are connected, think about what information do you want to retrieve. What is common, how to connect the two tables. Then you will know if you need a LEFT JOIN or a GROUP or a combination of both. Right now I can't tell why you have duplicates. Even if you group the result, do you know that this will solve your problem?

Comment: Could it be that you have employees, that have more than one job? In such case the Distinct will now help, because the employee name is the same, but the job description is different. Grouping will help, but the question is if the data is then correct? If this is the case, then you need to Group on EmployeeName.

Comment: I have added an example group by employee name in my answer. Try it out and modify it to meet you needs.

Comment: Thanks guy,  I have little confused when I express my question. Thanks again because your enthusiasm, I just edited my code. And I am viewing your edited answer.

Comment: Hi pasty, I do some change, it works.  , but each row in employee table be created, it must have at least one row in job table, or not it will so error 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can I do it with this errorr

Comment: Just check if the object is null or not, something like `if (data.JobObject != null) { data.JobObject.Property; ... }`. Without the code, I can't tell you where exactly the problem is.